# Do Cabal recognize packages installed by system package manager

Tags: haskell, linker, cabal, package-managers

I had lately linker problem during compilation of Haskell code and I wonder whether cabal can find packages installed by OS package manger e.g. I install package X which depends on Y but Y is already installed by package manger (not cabal). Will cabal install it own version of Y? Wouldn't that cause problem when linking?

Comment: Have a read through [SICP](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml). It has a section specifically devoted to this question (though you will need to read the earlier parts of the article to understand that section, so I won't link directly to it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cabal queries GHC to get a list of installed packages, and it will recognize packages installed by your package manager.